# Are we able to create a billing alarm from AWS Cloud Watch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch, alarm, billing

Unable to see the Billing in All Metrics tab, while creating an alarm in Amazon Cloud Watch for a billing alarm. I guess this feature is removed and can be achieved somehow differently, please assist.

Answer (score 3):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html):

> Billing metric data is stored in the **US East (N. Virginia)** Region and represents worldwide charges.

Thus, have to go to `us-east-1` region for Billing metrics.

To create CloudWatch alarm for the billing metrics also [need to be](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html#creating_billing_alarm_with_wizard) in `us-east-1`:

> If necessary, **change the Region to US East (N. Virginia)**. Billing metric data is stored in this Region and represents worldwide charges.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the **Receive Billing Alerts** option in your Billing Preferences pane with of your root account is not enabled.

To enable it,

> ```
> My Billing Dashboard -> Billing preferences
> ```

check the following and enter your billing alert email

- Receive Free Tier Usage Alerts
- Receive Billing Alerts

Click `Save preferences` :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Billing and Cost Management console.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Billing Preferences
3. Choose Receive Billing Alerts
4. Choose Save preferences.

Check the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html)